# How to add in a windows form project some columns and header without using databases?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I make in a c# windows application , columns and header?
Like this one:[image]

And yes , I would like to dynamically add rows .

How can I do that?

Comment: u mean u want fetch data from database??

Comment: Or do you just want a control like that?

Comment: just a control where I can dynamically add rows to it , I think this can be done using listview but I Don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add("Johnnie");

// I assume that you've already created dataGridView (in your form)
dataGridView.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: Ok it worked but how can I remove the option where I can add new rows?because I want this to be made from code not by the user.

Comment: DataGridView has properties such as AllowUserToAddRows, AllowUserToDeleteRows, etc. Please check the documentation links given by des.

Answer (score 1):

*You don't need ADO.NET DataTables when you don't use database*. Just add gridview to your form. Select your gridview, and at the bottom of properties window you'll see two links `Add Column...`, `Edit Columns...`. You can add required columns and set their types here.

Assume you have following class:

```
public class City
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Country { get; set; }
   public string CountryCode { get; set; }
   public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Add four columns of type DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to your GridView with headers `Country:`, `Country Code:`, `State:`, `City:` (you can make columns readonly). Then go to `Edit Columns` and specify for each column DataPropertyName. It should be property name of your City class, to which column will be bound. E.g. it should be `Name` property for column `City`.

Then create list of cities and assign it to GridView:

```
BindingList<City> cities = new BindingList<City>()
{
    new City() { Name = "Carros", Country = "France", CountryCode = "FRA" },
    new City() { Name = "Barcelona", Country = "Spain", State = "Catalonia" }
};

dataGridView.DataSource = cities;
```

If you will use `BindingList` instead of simple `List`, then changes on your cities list will affect data in DataGrid (i.e. when you add or remove cities):

```
void ButtonAddCity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cities.Add(new City() {
        Name = nameTextBox.Text,
        Country = countryTextBox.Text, 
        CountryCode = codeTextBox.Text,
        State = stateTextBox.Text
    }); 
}
```